# Asymptote - a large dot for vertices

Tags: graphics, xetex, asymptote, draw

I'm learning `asymptote` and I'm trying to figure out how to increase the size of dots.

For an example, when drawing this object:

```
size(0,0);

path cle=scale(2cm)*unitcircle;

draw(cle);

for(real i=0; i<=length(cle); i+=.2)
  {
    dot(point(cle,i));
    draw((0,0)--point(cle,i),dotted);
  }
```

I can use dots using `dot()`, but the dots are way to small to be used as vertices.

Could you help me enlarge the dots?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to Asymptote and to this site!

If you look up the `dot` and `draw` commands in the manual, you will see that they take a `pen` as an optional argument.

Try this...

```
dot(point(cle,i), 3+red);
```

You can also define the pen beforehand.  This would be useful if you were going to use the same pen many times.

```
pen peterPen = 5+blue;
dot(point(cle,i), peterPen);
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks,  it worked perfectly!